# React Native Networking Issues

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

Hi everyone im having some strange networking issues with react native.

When my app loads i try and load some data from a server using [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) (http library mentioned in react-native docs)

If i run the app with live debugging everything loads and works as expected. If i run it without debugging enabled my app does nothing, data does not load and i see no content. Im not sure what to do as the issue doesnt occur when in debugging mode.

Also my info.plist includes this key

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aghhh the issue was i was trying to use

```
var params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('param1', 'value1');
params.append('param2', 'value2');
axios.post('/foo', params);
```

When it clearly says `URLSearchParams` is only available in the browser!